# getting value from input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the value from the input field in the form.
the idea is to send this value later to the server and display other values ​​associated with it.

```
<form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off" id="my_form">
   <div class="txtb">{{form.date.label}} {{form.date}}</div>
   <div class="txtb"> <p class="txt"></p></div>
<input type="submit" value="send" class="btn" id="btn">
```

In the Input field I assigned a class="pole" and trying to print value.

```
$('.pole').on('input', function() {
  var val = $('.pole').val();
  $('.txt').html(val);
$('.txt').val(val);
});
```

but this does not work, how can this be done?

Comment: you want to display input value in p tag on input change ?

Comment: If you set value as html value of <p> it will not go to server as form values. You can use another input value in that case or better use input inside the form only?

Comment: @BInjal Patel yes. and try latter  using ajax to transfer to the server and get an additional field with select

Comment: @ВадимШаройкин are you using angular ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change`$('.pole').val()` to `$(this).val()` You should have to try like

```js
$('.pole').on('input', function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $('.txt').html(val);
  $('.txt').val(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" class="pole" placeholder="type here">
<p class="txt"></p>
```

Comment: whether this may not work due to the fact that the form is displayed from the backend model (django) ?

Comment: @ВадимШаройкин might be you can check it by `inspecting` .

Comment: I do not understand why this does not work in my case

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$(this)` to get the instance of current input with class=pole instead of `$('.pole')`, see below code

```
$('.pole').on('input', function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $('.txt').text(val);
});
```

Comment: value is not displayed in p tag

Comment: have you checked if `val` is showing current value properly? use `console.log` to print value in browser console

Answer (score 1):

As you want to submit value, you need to mention input field in html.
Have a look at [this demo](https://codepen.io/ftj07/pen/OJVVEyZ)

```
<form id="myForm" action="/action_page.php">
  First name: <input type="text" id="fname" value="Donald"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" id="lname" value="Duck"><br>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm()">
<p id="demo"></p>
</form> 

function submitForm() {
  var firstName = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  var lastName = document.getElementById("lname").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = lastName;
}
```

Comment: I want the value to be displayed not by pressing a button, but by input

Answer (score 1):

I think your input is sibling of paragraph. Try this:

```
$('.pole').on('keyup', function() {
   $(this).parent().find(".txt").html($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not able to find dom with `class` `txt` & `pole` but you can try this code

```
$('.pole').on('input', function() {
  // changed here
  var val = $(this).val();
  $('.txt').html(val);
  $('.txt').val(val);
});
```

Comment: value is not displayed in p tag